# How to annotate the type of `apply` in Python?

Tags: python, mypy

Is it possible to (precisely) annotate the type of an "apply" function in Python?

Untyped, the function is

```
def apply(f, args):
    return f(*args)
```

I would want to write something like

```
from typing import *

T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')
def apply(f: Callable[T,S], args: Tuple[T]) -> S:
    return f(*args)
```

but this doesn't work. `mypy` at least complains that the first argument to `Callable` must be a list...

Two examples of how `apply` might be used:

```
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y

def negate(x: int) -> int:
    return -x

apply(add, (x,y))
apply(negate, (x,))
```

P.S. Not that `Tuple[T]` doesn't quite make sense, even if `T` somehow represented a type list.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) you can see that the list asked in the signature `Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type], ReturnType]` is a list of type of variables

```
from typing import *

T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')
def apply(f: [[T],S], args: Tuple[T]) -> S:
    return f(*args)
```

Comment: While this works for single-argument functions, this doesn't allow `f` to be a function of multiple arguments.

Comment: Can you specify an example of a function and arguments that would be passed down?

Comment: You bet! I've put two examples call-sites in the original question.